# Missing table view in tkinker application

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter

I'm trying to display a content of a CSV file in tkinter application. But I'm keep getting an empty space instead of the table as shown in the image below. Can someone kindly help me to identify the issue that I have made there?

In the `LoadSaveTab` class, I'm pressing the <kbd>Display</kbd> button to display the dataframe content. Also, I imported,

```
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
from tkintertable import TableCanvas
```

to display the content of the csv file as a table

```
self.display_button = tk.Button(self,
                                text = 'Display',
                                font = ('Arial', 14),
                                bg = 'Green',
                                fg = 'Black',
                                command = lambda:
                                    load_data.Manipulate_data().display_csv_file(self)
```

`display_csv_file` method of `Manipulate_data()` class:

```
def display_csv_file(self,parent):
    try:
        self.file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = '/Desktop',
                                                    title = 'Select csv file',
                                                    filetypes = (('csv file','*.csv'),
                                                                 ('csv file','*.csv')))
        df = pd.read_csv(self.file_name)

        if (len(df)== 0):
            msg.showinfo('No records', 'No records')
        else:
            pass

        # Now display the DF in 'Table' object
        # under'pandastable' module
        self.f2 = tk.Frame(parent, height=300, width=500).place(relx=0.2,rely=0.3)
        print(self.f2)
        self.f2.pack(fill = both, expand=1)
        self.table = Table(self.f2, dataframe=TableModel.getSampleData(),read_only=True)
        self.table.show()

    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e)
        msg.showerror('Error in opening file',e)
```

[image]

Following is the error that I'm receiving.

[image]

I printed the object parent and it gives me, .!notebook.!loadsavetab

Comment: keyword `pass` just ignore all the code behind, it is this the current problem?

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't have a `Table` widget, so you must be using some other third-party module which you haven't mentioned. Since it's likely that most of us will have no idea what that is or how it's supposed to work, it's unlikely you'll get an answer to your question.

Comment: Your code will raise exception on `self.f2.pack(...)` because `self.f2` is None (result of `tk.Frame(...).place(...)`. Also should `self.f2.pack(fill=both, expand=1)` be `self.f2.pack(fill='both', expand=1)` instead?

Comment: As acw1668 mentioned, what I'm getting is the error is self.f2 none. I updated my question with requested information. Why self.f2 = tk.Frame(parent, height=300, width=500).place(relx=0.2,rely=0.3) is making any frame?

Answer (score 1):

using keyword `pass` will ignore all the code behind and this is may causing your blank display, replace with `break` or do not use `else` statement:

```
if (len(df)== 0):
    msg.showinfo('No records', 'No records')
else:
    break
```

or

```py
if (len(df)== 0):
    msg.showinfo('No records', 'No records')
```

Comment: While what you point out is true, it's largely harmless and has nothing to do with what the OP is asking (or why they're getting a blank window).

Comment: *"using keyword `pass` will ignore all the code behind"* It is not true.  It just does nothing on that line and proceeds.